# Using Articulate to run Python API in R, running undefinable strings

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I am looking to run the following Python API in **R**
https://github.com/uncomtrade/comtradeapicall

I have used reticulate for this.

One piece of code that calls the API is following:

**In Python**

```py
mydf = comtradeapicall.getFinalDataAvailability(subscription_key, typeCode='C', 
                                                freqCode='A', clCode='HS',
                                                period='2021', reporterCode=None)
```

**In R using reticulate**

```
subscription_key = "xxxxx1234..." #Confirmed as working

ctdr = import("comtradeapicall") #loads in the python package, comtradr


mydf = ctdr$getFinalDataAvailability(subscription_key, typeCode='C',
                                     freqCode='A', clCode='HS',
                                     period='2021', reporterCode=None)
```

However, I cannot run the call as None is is not defined. This produces

> Error: object 'None' not found

For example, the following runs fine.

**In R using reticulate and replace None**

```r
mydf = ctdr$getFinalDataAvailability(subscription_key, typeCode='C', freqCode='A', clCode='HS',
                                                period='2021', reporterCode='170')
```

A large number of calls require None and other objects to be used such as True. How do I overcome this in **R**?

I have tried setting `None = "None"`, however this produces an error Error in calling API: https://comtradeapi.un.org/data/v1....

Essentially, what do I need to define None as to be able to make it run within the Python API in R using articulate?

Answer (score 0):

Edited to add: try "none" instead of "None", above.  Else, I'd build from a minimal subprocess call using python's standard library.  Although, the more I look at this issue, perhaps "none" is not an acceptable parameter, per API documentation: https://unstats.un.org/wiki/display/comtrade/Areas+not+elsewhere+specified

Step 1: create a minimal R script: minimal_r.r that only contains:

```
print("Hello world in R!")
```

Step 2: create a minimal python script: minimal_py.py that only contains:

```
import subprocess

res = subprocess.call("Rscript /Users/dradecic/Desktop/script.R", shell=True)
res
```

Step 3: Once both are saved (in the same directory), navigate to the directory and run: python minimal_py.py

...and simply build from there!